# Как сделать hover на двойном треугольнике?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, анимация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо сделать, как на картинке выше. Элементы `<а>` соприкасаются друг с другом.

Двойной треугольник подсветки ссылки должен появляеться при наведении курсора.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37088367/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недостаёт здесь варианта с `clip-path`. Плюс этого варианта - меньше кода. На выходе такая же красивая картинка, как и с псевдоэлементами `:before` и `:after`.

```css
ul,li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none;}
a { color: white; text-decoration: none;} a:hover {color: #019CB2;}

ul {display: block; width: 100%; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; background: #019CB2;}
li {float: left; display: inline-block; padding: 0 20px; transition: all 0.5s; -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 80% 0, 100% 50%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0 50%); clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 80% 0, 100% 50%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0 50%);}
li:hover {background: #FFE902;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать градиенты, чтобы нарисовать каждую часть поверх цвета фона (`background-color`):

Если градиенты недоступны (более старый браузер), то у вас всё еще есть фон, чтобы показать другое состояние.

```css
nav {
  background: #009EAC
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(-250deg, #009EAC 0.5em, #009EAC 0.5em) top left no-repeat, linear-gradient(70deg, #009EAC 0.5em, #009EAC 0.5em) bottom left no-repeat, linear-gradient(250deg, #009EAC 0.5em, #009EAC 0.5em) top right no-repeat, linear-gradient(-70deg, #009EAC 0.5em, #009EAC 0em) bottom right no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 250, 0, 0), transparent) top left no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 80%;
  transition:background 0.5s;
}

a.active,
a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(-250deg, #009EAC 0.5em, transparent 0.5em) top left no-repeat, linear-gradient(70deg, #009EAC 0.5em, transparent 0.5em) bottom left no-repeat, linear-gradient(250deg, #009EAC 0.5em, transparent 0.5em) top right no-repeat, linear-gradient(-70deg, #009EAC 0.5em, transparent 0.5em) bottom right no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 250, 0, 0.9), transparent) top left no-repeat;
  background-color: #EEB01F;
  background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 80%;
}
```

```html
<nav><a href>LINK</a><a href class="active">ACTIVE HOVER STATE</a><a href>HOVER ME</a>
</nav>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37088560/7394871): @G-Cyr

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать `:before` и `:after` псевдо элементы

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  background: #019CB2;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
li:after,
li:before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
li:before {
  left: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 10px 20px 0;
  border-color: transparent #019CB2 transparent transparent;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
li:after {
  right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #019CB2;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
li:hover {
  background: #FFE902;
}
li:hover:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFE902;
}
li:hover:before {
  border-color: transparent #FFE902 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37088490/7394871): @Nenad Vracar